# Elixir macros, quoting and unquoting

Tags: elixir

I'm learning Elixir and experimenting with the Macro system.
I am trying to make a variable available to a block that will be wrapped with other code by a macro, but I am clearly doing something wrong.

This is my starting point macro, which works. I am ware that there are more idiomatic ways to iterate in Elixir, and I wrote it just as an exercise:

```
defmodule Loops do
  defmacro times(n, [do: block]) do
    quote do
      Enum.each(1..unquote(n), fn(_) -> unquote(block) end)
    end
  end
end

import Loops

times 3 do
  IO.puts "Hello!"
end
```

Now, what I want to accomplish is being able to reference the counter from the `do` block. So, if I give a proper name to the `fn` argument:

```
Enum.each(1..unquote(n), fn(_) -> unquote(block) end)
# becomes:
Enum.each(1..unquote(n), fn(counter) -> unquote(block) end)
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
times 3 do
  IO.puts "Hello! iteration n: #{counter}"
end
```

This however doesn't work and raises a `CompileError` because of `undefined function counter/0`. The error is raised from the `do` block I passed to the macro *invocation*, which I find a bit counterintuitive because I thought that the block would be *placed* in the expanded code when calling `unquote()`.

Am I approaching the problem in the wrong way, or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Kernel.var!/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#var!/2) to make `counter` an "unhygienic" variable. This will make sure it is available to the generated code without being renamed by Elixir's macro system.

```
defmodule Loops do
  defmacro times(n, [do: block]) do
    quote do
      Enum.each(1..unquote(n), fn(var!(counter)) ->
        unquote(block)
      end)
    end
  end
end

defmodule Main do
  require Loops

  def main do
    Loops.times 3 do
      IO.puts "Hello! iteration n: #{counter}"
    end
  end
end

Main.main
```

Output:

```
Hello! iteration n: 1
Hello! iteration n: 2
Hello! iteration n: 3
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.